# Why there has many shadow of the view while I drag the view-item?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I try to draw a rectange than can move around in a view.but when I drag item in then view, there has many shadow of it.  If I remove `View.drawForeground` method, it work well, but in my case, I need them all.  The `View.drawForeground` in need to draw foreground outline(**The `View.drawForeground` method show what i wanted border**) while resize the window or drag the view-item in it.
So how can I solve it?

**The code**

```py
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Node(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(-200, -200, 400, 400)

    def paint(self, painter: QPainter, option: QStyleOptionGraphicsItem, widget:QWidget):
        painter.drawRect(option.rect)


class View(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        scene = QGraphicsScene()
        node = Node()

        node.setPos(-0, -0)
        scene.setSceneRect(-200, -200, 400, 400)
        scene.addItem(node)

        self.setScene(scene)
        self.setCacheMode(QGraphicsView.CacheBackground)
        self.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView.BoundingRectViewportUpdate)

    def drawForeground(self, painter: QPainter, rect: QRectF):
        pen = QPen(QBrush(Qt.blue), 2, Qt.DotLine)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.drawRect(rect.adjusted(10, 10, -10, -10))


app = QApplication([])
view = View()
view.resize(600, 600)
view.show()
app.exec_()
```

**The effect**
[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to paint the update rect in `drawForeground()`? What are you trying to achieve there?

Comment: I update `drawForeground` for I need to draw something in it, I am learning it and maybe it will be useful for me in the future time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a portion of the *visible* scene changes, the graphics view paints the background (`drawBackground()`), the scene, and then the foreground that are included in the region that was interested by the changes.

Such changes include parts of the scene that were *previously* occupied by an item and that require repainting in order to draw what was behind that item.

This is done in order to provide better optimization: if only a small portion of the scene requires an update, there's no use in repainting all of it. Consider that every item could require lots of computations for its painting (gradients, coordinate, shapes, etc), so they should be only painted when absolutely necessary.

If you move an item, not only the scene needs to paint it at the new coordinates, but it's also needed to draw what was previously covered (even partially hidden) by that item at its previous position.

Consider a `20x10` rectangle created at `0, 0`: the scene will be updated only within the boundaries of that rectangle (`0, 0, 20, 10`).

Then you move the rectangle at `40, 20`; this will cause the view to schedule an update of the previous area (in order to "clear" it and possibly draw what was "behind" it) *and* the new rectangle.

This means that `drawBackground()`, the scene painting, and `drawForeground()` will all be called for both `(0, 0, 20, 10)` *and* `(40, 20, 20, 10)` (actually, it will be a full region including those rectangles).

In your case, the result is that the "shadows" you're seeing are the portions of the scene that were redrawn in order to "clear" the previous position of the item.

This can also be noted when the program is started: the dashed line is exactly inside the view margins, since the view is being shown the first time, so it needs to be completely painted.

If you want to draw the dashed border when moving the item, there are various possibilities depending on your requirements, but consider that it is almost always the item's responsibility to do its own painting, since you cannot rely on the `drawForeground()` method for the above reasons: if you have more than one item, you should always ensure that the previously selected item gets updated in order to clear its border, which would make things unnecessarily complex.

A possible approach could be to use the `ItemIsSelectable` flag, and check if the item is selected in *its* paint method.
Note that: this will cause updates whenever the selection state of the item changes, the item will still be selected after moving, and it will stay selected even if it wasn't moved at all. In order to deselect an item, ctrl+click it, click anywhere outside it, or use `setSelected(False)` programmatically.

```
class Node(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFlags(
            QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(-200, -200, 400, 400)

    def paint(self, painter: QPainter, option: QStyleOptionGraphicsItem, widget:QWidget):
        painter.drawRect(self.boundingRect())
        if self.isSelected():
            pen = QPen(QBrush(Qt.blue), 2, Qt.DotLine)
            painter.setPen(pen)
            painter.drawRect(self.boundingRect().adjusted(10, 10, -10, -10))
```

<sup>Note: while the style option is usually initialized on the current bounding rect, it *could* actually be different, as the option rect could have other purposes; for better consistency, you should use the `boundingRect()` (or, better, the rectangle used for that returned value). Also note that for better performance it's usually suggested to make the pen an instance attribute instead of creating a new one every time. Finally,
remember that painting should *always* be within the bounding rect, which is *very* important if you're using a non default pen width (read more in the [`paint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#paint) documentation).</sup>

Alternatively, you can check if the item is the *mouse grabber*, which is an object that will receive **all** mouse events sent to a scene. A movable item automatically becomes a mouse grabber when pressing the left button on it and stops being one when the button is released. In order to achieve that, we need to implement both mouse press and release events in order to trigger an update, otherwise the item won't be repainted until it's actually required (when it's moved).

```
class Node(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(-200, -200, 400, 400)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
        self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        self.update()

    def paint(self, painter: QPainter, option: QStyleOptionGraphicsItem, widget:QWidget):
        painter.drawRect(self.boundingRect())
        if self.scene().mouseGrabberItem() == self:
            pen = QPen(QBrush(Qt.blue), 2, Qt.DotLine)
            painter.setPen(pen)
            painter.drawRect(self.boundingRect().adjusted(10, 10, -10, -10))
```

Comment: Hi friend,in my case the `Node` item only draw a rectangle without dash-line border, the dash-line border in the `Node`  is not I wanted that when I drag it was created, I need to eliminate this bad effect. And I had read your answer and use your code, it don't work at all.

Comment: @jett sorry but "it doesn't work" is really not useful. Please try to clarify what you want to achieve, why my solution doesn't work for you, and, as already asked, why are you implementing `drawForeground()`.

Comment: The `drawForeground`  is used to  draw outline of the scene so I can see it's border.
I copy your code not work.maybe I should use `drawBackground` method.

Comment: `drawBackground ` work fine but `drawForeground ` work not I wanted, I don't know why them is different.

Comment: So, you only need to draw the border "inside" the view?

Comment: Yes, a visible border in the scene.

Comment: @jett please try to be more clear. "a visible border in the scene" can mean a lot of thigs. Which border should be visible? The border near the margins of the view, or within the item that is being moved? And when should that border be visible? You edited the question, but now it's even more confusing. Can you provide an image that could **exactly** show what you need?